# How do I upload to dropbox using dropnet?

Tags: c#, dropnet

I am using DropNet. I have problem with upload file into DropBox. 
I am sure the connection with dropbox in fine. when I changed the method of upload to create file and delete file method that works fine.
I really can not see any problem that why is not uploading? I use exactly same API as DropNet.

```
protected void Btn_upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            if (Session["DropNetUserLogin"] != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    _client.UseSandbox = true;
                    _client.UploadFile("/", FileUpload1.FileName, FileUpload1.FileBytes);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    litOutput.Text = "Error in upload user login in session " + ex.Message;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                litOutput.Text = "Session expired...";
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            litOutput.Text = "You did not specify a file to upload.";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does FileUpload1.FileName contain? Is it just the filename or the entire path for the file? What sort of error do you get (if any)?

Comment: Hi GaborSch, Thank you so much for your quick reply. i did not get any error, its compile. When I debug over it. FileUpload.FileName its the local name of file that I selected. (it's just the filename, eg. a.txt)

Comment: Hmm... While debugging, have you checked that FileUpload1.FileBytes actually has any bytes in it?

Comment: yes, it is. Thats why I felt its strange.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code which worked for me, hoping that this may help you:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var dlg = new OpenFileDialog();

    dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt";

    Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

    if (result == true)
    {
        string filename = dlg.FileName;
        FileNameTextBox.Text = filename;
    }

    var x = @"/" + Path.GetFileName(FileNameTextBox.Text);

    _client.UploadFile("/", Path.GetFileName(FileNameTextBox.Text), File.ReadAllBytes(@"" + FileNameTextBox.Text));
}
```